# Concrete Mathematics - Understanding the generalization in chapter 1 (Josephus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

A couple of months ago, I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579098/concrete-mathematics-how-is-it-that-a2n-1-2an) question, and received a solid answer which provided a thorough level of detail and analysis on the logic behind the initial proof for $A(n) = f(n)$.

To clarify, his goal is to show that this recurrence:

$$f(1) = \alpha;$$
$$f(2n) = 2f(n) + \beta;$$
$$f(2n + 1) = 2f(n) + \gamma;$$

is equivalent to the following closed form:

$$f(n) = A(n)\alpha + B(n)\beta + C(n)\gamma;$$

Deducing that,

$$A(n) = 2^m;$$
$$B(n) = 2^m - l - 1;$$
$$C(n) = l$$

However, this requires a proof to be certain.

In order to do this, he first proves that $A(n) = 2^m$ through the following recurrence:

$$A(1) = 1;$$ 
$$A(2n) = 2A(n) + \beta$$
$$A(2n + 1) = 2A(n) + \gamma$$

for $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) = (1, 0, 0)$

Then, using $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) = (1, 0, 1)$ he provides:

$$1 = \alpha;$$
$$2n = 2 \times 1 + \beta$$
$$2n + 1 = 2 \times 1 + \gamma$$

Which satisfies $f(n) = n$.

For $f(n) = 1$, he provides:

$$1 = \alpha;$$
$$1 = 2\times1 + \beta$$
$$1 = 2\times1 + \gamma$$

Which gives us $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) = (1, -1, -1)$

What I'm trying to figure out is the big picture behind all of this. My understanding is that this technique of generalization for $f$ can be used as a *framework* for solving different kinds of problems using the fact that we can essentially represent any value $n$ as $2^m + l$, and then derive a recurrence of the given form, using arbitrary constants $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ for some arbitrary purpose.

What I don't understand is... how exactly is it that these proofs actually  show this is true? I understand, given the question I provided and its corresponding answer, that they're designed to fill gaps in areas where representing $f(n)$ through some form of these constants requires that $f(n)$ be defined for all n, and that this is a means of providing such proof.

How is it that these statements show this fact when they *require* that $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ be defined to specific values for each case?

Comment: Could someone kindly spare a few words on this question? I too struggle to understand: how can you justify combining special cases when they each require their specific set of parameters? @aboutblank have you figured it out for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking also gets covered in [this other stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017498/mathematical-explanation-for-the-repertoire-method?rq=1) but in summary it's really more "educated" guesswork to finding combinations of values of $(\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma)$ such that when all 3 combinations are added together they yield the closed form solution.

Here's a link to the [Stony Brooke course that covers the first chapter of Concrete Mathematics too](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~cse547/chapter1.pdf).